# PrimeNG Accordion doesn't work and display properly

Tags: css, angular, angular6, primeng

I am try to use primeNG Accordion according to the [official documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion)

Here is my code:

```
<p-accordion [multiple]="true">
    <p-accordionTab header="Godfather I">
        The story begins  as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, overseeshis daughter's wedding. His beloved son ichael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. T hrough Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family, kind and benevolent to those who give respect, but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family.
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Godfather II">
        Francis Ford Coppola's legendary continuation and sequel to his landmark 1972 film, The_Godfather parallels the young Vito Corleone's rise with his son Michael's spiritual fall, deepening The_Godfather's depiction of the dark side of the American dream. In the early 1900s, the child Vito flees his Sicilian village for America after the local Mafia kills his family. Vito struggles to make a living, legally or illegally, for his wife and growing brood in Little Italy, killing the local Black Hand Fanucci after he demands his customary cut of the tyro's business. With Fanucci gone, Vito's communal stature grows.
   </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Godfather III">
        After a break of more than  15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family. Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate.
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

And I make sure that `import { AccordionModule } from 'primeng/accordion'` and import `AccordionModule` are in app.module.ts

**Issue #1**: I had an error: `ERROR Error: "Found the synthetic listener @tabContent.done. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application."`

Do I actually need to include `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule`? It is not mentioned in the official doc

**Issue #2**: I added `NoopAnimationsModule` and now the issue is gone, but the display was horrible.

It seems the accordion content and the headers are overlapped:
[image]

one tab is active:
[image]

Please help. Feel free to correct me if anything is misused. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: For Issue #1, from primeNg setup guide: "*... you need to import BrowserAnimationsModule to your application. If you prefer not to use NoopAnimationsModule instead.*"

Comment: Do you have primeng.css and one of the theme.css installed?

Comment: For Issue #2, clearly the styles are different than primeNg default styles.  Did you customize the CSS?  If so put the CSS in your question.

Comment: Without seeing the css, my best guess is you have a selector that sets `overflow` which is overwriting primeNg's own classes.

Comment: Thanks David and Daniel. Yes, you are right. The problem is in the css. I didn't consider the `primeng.min.css` as dependency. Thank you for pointing out. Now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the contents not hiding is because you don't have `primeng.css` included in your page, PrimeNG components automatically applies a fixed set of css classes to their components, and in your case this is the following class that is responsible for hiding the contents of your accordion panels:

```
.ui-accordion-content-wrapper-overflown {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to David and Daniel in the comment section.

For issue #1: Yes, I need to import `BrowserAnimationsModule`

For issue #2: the `primeng.min.css` is missing. I have to add "/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" in angular.json

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone arriving here wondering why, having checked everything possible, this component is still not working, the answer lies in the imports. I had both BrowserAnimationsModule and NoopAnimationsModule imported in AppModule. The order of the imports matters. You need to import NoopAnimationsModule before BrowserAnimationsModule.

It will also work if you remove the NoopAnimationsModule import altogether, but in my case I've left it there, because I don't know yet if it's being used anywhere else in the project.

- PrimeNG: 17.3.2
- Angular: 17.0.8
- Angular animations: 17.0.8